# How to change button content and reload it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a lot of `button` elements in a `grid` matrix. Each of them has name as follows `btnXY` where `x` and `y` are the row and column indexes of the grind matrix.

So, I am dynamically selecting such button and trying to change its content like this:

```
  Button emptyButton = (Button)gridMain.FindName("btn" + currentTag);
  emptyButton.Content = "someText";
```

The issue is that the `Content` is not changed in the application. I believe this is because the `emptyButton` holds a copy of the selected button, not a reference.

Is there a way to select the button as reference and work with it?

Comment: Can you show your XAML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `FindName` method will get **the reference** of control.

In your case, the method will return the reference of `emptyButton`. If button be found, content will be updated.

You issue must be that the name of button is not right. If the name is not right, the method will not throw any error but will do nothing.

So, you should check the 'currentTag' parameter.